# How to bypass SSL authentication in if_http_client ABAP consumer?

Tags: rest, ssl, abap, sap-basis, sap-ariba

**TLDR:** Basically, my question would be if there is any method on class `if_http_client` or any ABAP class that can turn off SSL verification? Because it seems that it only works when it is disabled. If not then how do I bypass this error?

**Long description**:

I am able to receive response using Postman but when trying to code it on ABAP, I cannot get response. I want to receive token from `api-eu.ariba.com`. Here's my inputs on Postman:

- URL: https://api-eu.ariba.com/v2/oauth/token
- Method: `POST`
- Headers:

  - `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - `Authorization: Basic + API key`
- Body:

  - `grant_type: openapi_2lo`

When I try these inputs on Postman, I am able to get response **only when SSL verification is disabled**. I have tested this also in Python as there is a parameter in requests to disable SSL verification and able to get the same response. But when I try this on ABAP (using **`if_http_client`**), this is where I get HTTP communication error upon receiving response.

> Direct connect to api-eu.ariba.com:443 failed: NIECONN_REFUSED(-10)

So far, I've tried the following:

- Install public cert for SAP Ariba EU (RSA) into `STRUST`
- Tried to add OAUTH profile from `OA2C_CONFIG` (I'm not sure if I did the config correctly). Tried to set token but get error:

  > HTTP failure, processing failed, invalid state, invalid timeout or others Error calling EXECUTE_CC_FLOW.

I have very little Basis knowledge so I'm not sure if I did the `OA2C_CONFIG` correctly and not knowledgeable with ABAP REST API related classes.

ABAP code snippet:

```
*Creation of New IF_HTTP_Client Object
  CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>create_by_url
    EXPORTING
      url                = lv_endpoint
      ssl_id             = 'ANONYM'
    IMPORTING
      client             = lo_client
    EXCEPTIONS
      argument_not_found = 1
      plugin_not_active  = 2
      internal_error     = 3
      OTHERS             = 4.

IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.
* Handle errors
ENDIF.

lo_client->propertytype_logon_popup = 0.
*lo_client->request->set_method( if_http_request=>co_request_method_post ).

CALL METHOD lo_client->request->set_method( 'POST' ).
lo_client->request->set_header_field( name = 'Authorization' value =  lv_auth ).
lo_client->request->set_header_field( name = 'Content-Type' value = lv_contyp ).
lo_client->request->set_form_field( name  = 'grant_type' value = lv_grantype ).

lo_client->send( ).
IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.
* Handle errors
ENDIF.

CALL METHOD lo_client->receive
  EXCEPTIONS
    http_communication_failure = 1
    http_invalid_state         = 2
    http_processing_failed     = 3
    OTHERS                     = 4.
IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.
  lo_client->get_last_error(
    IMPORTING
    message = lv_response  ).
  WRITE: / lv_response.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.

  ENDIF.

ENDIF.
```

Edit: Able to found a parameter on class:

```
CL_HTTP_CLIENT->CREATE_BY_URL
```

called `DO_NOT_USE_CLIENT_CERT`, that is `abap_false` by default. Changed the value to `abap_true` but this didn't work.

Comment: 1) For information, your ABAP code doesn't refer to the profile and configuration that you defined in `OA2C_CONFIG` (missing `CL_OAUTH2_CLIENT`...), you seem to do OAuth2 full custom which is not recommended. 2) If you use `ANONYM`, make sure that you have defined your certificate in the Client Anonymous PSE of `STRUST`. 3) I don't see any reason why your code wouldn't work except if the rest of the code you didn't share is wrong like values of variables (please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: To answer some points:1) I did try OA2C_CONFIG when connecting via url cl_http_client=>create_by_url didn't work. 2) I did try to comment out using ssl_id and still didnt work. In STRUST I asked basis to install the CRT file in SAP Ariba public repo [link](https://support.ariba.com/item/view/192337) but didnt work still. 4) All the params in the code were copied from Postman (where I got response). In postman, I am able to get response only when SSL verification is disabled so I was thinking of ways in ABAP side how to do that.

Comment: @SandraRossi as for the code, that is the full code. I didnt show the values for the header and body variables. I was thinking maybe SAP is not allowing HTTPS connection unless SSL Certificates are added?

Comment: 1) You say "did try OA2C_CONFIG" and "`cl_http_client`" but again you MUST also use `cl_oauth2_client`. 2) Why commenting out ssl_id? (FYI `create_by_url` without `ssl_id` means the PSE Client Anonymous/ANONYM). How did you make sure that the certificate is installed in the PSE of STRUST used by your program (`ssl_id` = PSE ID). 3) Don't omit what is "obvious", just post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all values. 5) SAP allows HTTPS connection only if you install the Web site/CA certificate in `STRUST`.

Comment: I just realize that you got the certificate from the "[link](https://support.ariba.com/item/view/192337)" you have indicated above, but usually we simply take the certificate from the Web site via the Web browser, download and install it in `STRUST`.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are most of the way there.

a) TRUST ariba.com in STRUST.

use a web browser to go to the site , click on the padlock and down load their cert.
[image: Check cert and download]

[image: The export the cert]

T-Code STRUST
Import the cert. Apply it to  CLIENT SSL Anon and Standard PSE sections.

BUT NIEHOST errors are different to SSL areas.
So you should also check the DNS and if the SAP system can even reach that url.

Sometimes you need to configure a CLIENT proxy in TCode SICF.
If you organization uses a proxy for external HTTP connections, then that must be configured in SICF client proxy settings.

[image: Client proxy settings]

Comment: Hi we are able to connect to host: 'api-eu.ariba.com' from SM59 after Basis added proxy host and service. thanks! The problem now would be connecting to 'https://api-eu.ariba.com/v2/oauth/token' from ABAP side which we wanted to connect retrieve the token

Answer (score 1):

We are now able connect via SM59.

- Basis added proxy host and service.
- Added path prefix: '/v2/oauth/token'
- Used the destination and connected to Ariba using `cl_http_client=>create_by_destination` from ABAP side and passed the parameters.
- OAUTH Profile is not needed for this case.

Thanks for the suggestions!
[Test Connection OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JbpD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I checked api-eu.ariba.com SSL and it looks valid. Maybe you date/time didn't correct or root certificate is missing.

You can enable ICM trace at t-code SMICM. Create a test connection at SM59 then click test connection button. Then check the ICM log. You will get more details in the log.

You need to configure TLS version and handshake methods for SAP. Maybe your SAP only accept TLS 1.3 because of security reason but the endpoint not supporting it.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but I asked basis to install CRT file in STRUST from public repo [link](https://support.ariba.com/item/view/192337) but this didn't work. I tried to do ICM trace but I only get this response: `Direct connect to https://api-eu.ariba.com/:443 failed: NIEHOST_UNKNOWN(-2) {00c7c7a4} {root-id=42010A062D121EEDB3F37AAD1639E8F1} [icxxconn.c 4216]` Is there any options how to disable SSL verification from abap side?

Comment: In SM59; these are my parameters: `host: https://api-eu.ariba.com/` `port=443`. Under security, SSL is active, SSL Certificate is Default SSL client (also changed to Anonymous) but connection error is the same

Comment: @user21525821 host should not contain the scheme identifier "`https://`". What you indicate in "SSL Certificate" must be the same PSE where you have loaded the ariba certificate in STRUST. If you use `SM59`, you must use `cl_http_client=>create_by_destination` instead of `cl_http_client=>create_by_url`.

Comment: @SandraRossi sorry for the confusion. there is part of a code where I used `cl_http_client=>create_by_destination` with SM59 destination to test for workaround. SM59 connection fails issuing the same error. https has been removed from the host but outputs the same error.  I use `cl_http_client=>create_by_url` to connect directly to URL but it fails so I tried using the SM59 approach (setting up SM59 and use `cl_http_client=>create_by_destination` ; with and without OAuth profiles which yields to same errors).

Comment: NIEHOST_UNKNOWN is meaning that, SAP cannot resolve given domain name. You can try it with report RSBDCOS0. Use "ping api-eu.ariba.com" command and press enter in the input.

Comment: @mkysoft I am trying to ping to api ariba but it is taking too long. While waiting for response, I tried to perform trace in SMICM but I do not know how to make of it. Please see trace. Thanks

Comment: IcmIConnConnect: direct connect to api-eu.ariba.com:443
NiHLGetNodeAddr: get addr for hostname 'api-eu.ariba.com' (mode=0)
NiHLGetNodeAddr: found hostname 'api-eu.ariba.com' in cache (valid-name)
NiIGetNodeAddr: hostname 'api-eu.ariba.com' = addr 34.159.251.130
NiIGetServNo: servicename '443' = port 443
NiICreateHandle: hdl 204 state NI_INITIAL_CON
NiIBindLocalCheck: 34.159.251.130 -> not a local address (rc 7/99)
 -> Cannot assign requested address
NiIInitSocket: set default settings for new hdl 204/sock 43 (I4; ST)

Comment: @mkysoft i tried to ping to ariba on RSBDCOS0 but it says "error; Maximum runtime exceeded"

Comment: It looks network issue. I think you need request a help from basis team. You can request a working SM59 connection from them.